# Sorting pandas dataframe to get min value along diagonal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe, it is used for a heatmap. I would like the minimal value of each column to be along the diagonal.

I've sorted the columns using

```
data = data.loc[:, data.min().sort_values().index]
```

This works. Now I just need to sort the values such that the index of the min value in the first column is row 0, then the min value of second column is row 1, and so on.

Example

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = [[5,1,9],
        [7,8,6],
        [5,3,2]]


data = pd.DataFrame(data)
#sns.heatmap(data)


data = data.loc[:, data.min().sort_values().index]
#sns.heatmap(data) # Gives result in step 1
# Step1, Colunsm sorted by min value, 1, 2, 5
data = [[1,9,5],
        [8,6,7],
        [3,2,5]]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
#sns.heatmap(data)
# How do i perform step two, maintaining column order.
# Step 2, Rows sorted by min value 1,2,7
data = [[1,9,5],
        [3,2,5],
        [8,6,7]]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.heatmap(data)
```

Is this possible in panda in a clever way?

Comment: can you include an example of what you'd like your sorted DataFrame to look like?

Comment: Can you post your dataframe and expected output, in other words a [mcve]

Comment: @HenryWoody I've added a small reproduceable example.

Comment: @CodeMonkey so the last `data`is your desired output?

Comment: So does the order within a column not matter as long as the min for the column is at the diagonal point?

Comment: The matrix is a distance matrix between two different values list along the first and second axis. matrxi[i,j] = distance(list1, list2), now i would to sort this matrix to get the most likely candidates along the diagional. Do this makes sense?
So yes, the order within a column do not matter as long as you rearrange the entire row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but you've already done the following to sort column

```
data = data.loc[:, data.min().sort_values().index]
```

the same trick could also be applied to sort row

```
data = data.loc[data.min(axis=1).sort_values().index, :]
```

Comment: Works awesome. Comming from R and dplyr some of this panda stuff is completly backwards :)

Comment: I had to jitter 0.0 values to help the sorting a bit, but thats ok for plotting the data.

Answer (score 2):

***Setup***

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[5, 1, 9], [7, 8, 6], [5, 3, 2]])
```

You can accomplish this by using `argsort` of the diagonal elements of your sorted DataFrame, then indexing the DataFrame using these values.

***Step 1***
Use your initial sort:

```
data = data.loc[:, data.min().sort_values().index]

   1  2  0
0  1  9  5
1  8  6  7
2  3  2  5
```

***Step 2***
Use `np.argsort` with `np.diag`:

```
data.iloc[np.argsort(np.diag(data))]

   1  2  0
0  1  9  5
2  3  2  5
1  8  6  7
```

Answer (score 0):

To move some values around so that the min value within each column is placed along the diagonal you could try something like this:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    min_index = data.iloc[:, i].idxmin()
    if data.iloc[i,i] != data.iloc[min_index, i]:
        data.iloc[i,i], data.iloc[min_index,i] = data.iloc[min_index, i], data.iloc[i,i]
```

Basically just swap the min with the diagonal.